# saving numbers to excel thinks its the time javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, format

I'm saving numbers into excel using javascript with format 0:0.2 and similar (min:sec.milsec) and when I open excel it thinks its the time, as the hour. For example, 0:0.2 it takes it like 12AM. 
Any ideas to change saving format so it wont think its time as the hour?
Thanks.

P.s
Saving it normally, no signs before and after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What can you change? Javascript or just Excel data?

With Javascript, you can add "0:" before time string.

In Excel, you can divide imported time data by 60.

Comment: yeah, it probably it..and also relate to saving data in excel as a string in server and not Custom.